# Why this haskell code cannot be compiled

Tags: haskell

I was trying to compile a haskell game code, this code generates three thread, one for infinite loop, one for collecting user's interaction, one for triggering the events. However, the code cannot be compiled and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Random
import Text.Printf

data Msg = C Char | Time
data Event = C Char | Time Char

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetEcho stdin False

  -- shared resources
  chan <- newEmptyMVar
  removedDigits <- newEmptyMVar
  unmatchedDigits <- newEmptyMVar
  numberOfGuesses <- newEmptyMVar

  --starting the generating thread and the user thread
  forkIO $ generatingThread chan
  forkIO $ userThread chan

  --the main loop
  if mainloop chan == True then "Congratulations! You won!" else "Better luck next time!"
  return()

  mainloop :: Chan c -> Bool
  let mainloop = do
  if length unmatchedDigits >= 10 
    then return False
  Event <- readChan c
  if Event == "timer"
    then unmatchedDigits ++ param
    else if testGuessedNumber param unmatchedDigits == True 
      then 
        removeMatchedDigit 
        if length unmatchedDigits == 0
        then return True
  mainloop c

-- Generating Thread aka event thread generating the random numbers 
generatingThread :: Chan msgChan -> IO ()
generatingThread msgChan = forever $ do
  publishTimerEvent msgChan 1000000

publishTimerEvent :: Chan msgChan -> Int delay ()
publishTimerEvent msgChan = do
  c <- getRandomChar
  putMVar msgChan ("timer" c)
  threadDelay newDelay
  velocity <- 0.9
  if delay * velocity < 100
    then newDelay <- 100
    else newDelay <- delay * velocity
  publishTimerEvent msgChan newDelay

getRandomChar :: Char c ()
getRandomChar = do
  i <- randomRIO (0,9)
  let c = "0123456789" !! i
  return c

-- User Thread
userThread :: MVar Msg -> IO ()
userThread chan = forever $ do
  c <- getChar
  putMVar chan (C c)
  showStr(show c)

testGuessedNumber :: Int -> Int -> Bool
testGuessedNumber a b
    | a == b    = True
    | otherwise = False

-- Shows the given string at the left edge of the current terminal line after
-- having blanked out the first 20 characters on that line.
showStr :: String -> IO ()
showStr s = putStr ("\r" ++ replicate 20 ' ' ++ "\r" ++ s)
```

The error is "test.hs:36:3: error: parse error on input ‘Event’"

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to compile the code?

Comment: Hi, Jason, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Although you've explained well what your problem is, it'll probably be difficult for you to get a good answer because your code is relatively large, and it will take a while for anyone who could answer to even go through it and find the parts that could be causing the problem.

You should do some tests yourself, find which parts of the code are more likely to be causing issues, and then update your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will help ensure you get quality answers.

Comment: Thanks, the error is "test.hs:36:3: error: parse error on input ‘Event’".

Comment: In the future, please include enough code (including imports) to allow others to try compiling your code themselves. That said, I suspect the issue may be due to improper use of if-statements. Every if-statement must be structured like `if <condition> then <value> else <value>`. I see 2 if-statements in the `mainloop` function that are not set up this way.

Answer (score 1):

Variable  names can not begin with uppercase letters, such as `Event`.  Try renaming the variable to something like `event`.

Comment: While correct, this is not the problem. You could match against the data constructor `Event` in a do-notation bind.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, all `if ... then ... else` blocks must have all their components; what would the result be otherwise?

The problem is that the compiler was expecting an `else`, but it actually got `Event`. That said, you have more problems than a simple parse error. `return` does not do what you think it does. For example, this code will print `hi`.

```
main = do
  return ()
  putStrLn "hi"
```

The `return` function simply lifts a value into a monad, it doesn't stop the computation or anything like that. Here is what your probably want to have:

```
...
if length unmatchedDigits >= 10 
  then return False
  else do
    Event <- readChan c
    if Event == "timer"
      then ...
      else ...
```

This way, nothing happens after the if block, so the function just ends there, with the last value as `False` (if `length unmatchedDigits >= 10`) or continues on properly (if `length unmatchedDigits < 10`).

You also almost certainly don't want to use `Event` (uppercase E), because that would mean it is a data constructor. You probably meant `event` (lowercase e), which is just an ordinary variable name.

Additionally: This is very, very non-idiomatic Haskell. You *definitely* don't need MVars in this situation, and *certainly* not four of them. `Chan`s are not the same thing as `MVar`s, and you don't need either one unless you are doing heavy-duty multi-threading. I *highly* recommend you completely rewrite this and try to minimize the amount of code that uses `IO` (it should be maybe 10-15 lines of `IO` code in this example, probably less).

This is not Java; you don't need to name your variables in your type signature (`Chan msgChan -> Int delay ()`), nor do you need to write wrapper functions for standard library functions to monomorphize their type. `testGuessedNumber` is *literally the same function as* `(==)`.

You will have much more success if you revisit basic, pure function syntax and understand how problems are solved in Haskell than with trying to emulate another language. Read some [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) or [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/).