# How to create a share variables in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm new for Haskell. Recently, I was trying to create a game by Haskell. In that game, I use Concurrent to create multiple threads.

```
data Msg = C Char | Time

forkIO $ userThread chan
forkIO $ processThread startTimer

userThread :: MVar Msg -> IO ()
userThread chan = forever $ do
  c <- getChar
  putMVar chan (C c)
  showStr(show c)

processThread :: MVar Msg -> IO ()
processThread chan = forever $ do
  threadDelay (startTimer)
  putMVar chan (Time)
```

I don't know how to define any other data shared between threads. Can I define a variable like C++ (static double xxx) and be visited by any function?

Comment: Could you give some C++ code illustrating what exactly you mean by “shared variable” here, how you intend to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, such variables are created in `main`, or another IO action.

```
main = do
   chan <- newEmptyMVar
   startTimer <- newEmptyMVar
   ...
   forkIO $ userThread chan
   forkIO $ processThread startTimer
   ...
```

There are some ways to declare "global variables" (mostly `IORef`s and `MVar`s), but they involve unsafe functions, and are best to be avoided, especially by beginners. Such globals are mostly unnecessary, and it's often better to pass a few arguments around, even if it requires more typing.

In more advanced code, one might use a `ReaderT r IO` monad to reduce the verbosity of the code which simply passes the `MVar`s around. But at the beginning, passing variables around is fine.

Comment: This works, and will give you the shared state you are looking for, but it is definitely an anti-pattern if you don't actually need multiple threads. I think OP should adapt to FP patterns because they will produce cleaner and more idiomatic code. It's *much* better to use a `StateT GameState` or similar than to pass around MVars and pollute your entire codebase with `IO`. [Extremely relevant previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215607/why-this-haskell-code-cannot-be-compiled)